# Multiple nested if conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

I have a dataframe (DF) with size (2000 rows x 10 columns).

The structure of the code is multiple nested if conditions:

```
DF['NewColumn']=''

for i in range (0, len(DF))
  if condition
    define variable etc
    if condition
      DF['NewColumn'].values[i]= some value
    else:
      DF['NewColumn'].values[i]= some value
```

etc

Basically, I loop over each row of the dataframe, check the conditions and populate each row of a new column  according to the set of if conditions.

Apologies if my question is not specific enough but I am looking for way to code this problem more efficiently. I am keen to hear your thoughts.

Can i use a class or vectorise? I am not sure how to restructure my problem

Many Thanks

Comment: can you provide some data and more info on `condition` ?

Comment: Does your `condition` depend on values in `DF`? What about `some value`?

Comment: @amaslenn  yes some if conditions depend on values in  DF. "some value"  also depends on values in DF. The conditions check if some threshold have been breached or whether the some values in DF belong to certain categories

Answer (score 0):

You can vectorize your loop like this

```
temp = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
condition1 = (temp["A"] > 20) & (temp["B"] < 20)
temp["NewColumn"] = condition1.astype(int)
condition2 = (temp["C"] > 20) & (temp["A"] < 50)
temp["NewColumn2"] = np.where(condition2, "between", "out")
```

Comment: @ J. Doe  is it possible to use a class or a function to achieve the same outcome?